# submitting a form through ajax for each ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

please guys, have some posts which i outputted from my database and now i want to make a comment form for each post and the form will be submitted through ajax method, but my problem is

1. the ajax method works for only the first outputted post and the form inserts into the database the `mysqli_num_rows($query)`. ie if `mysqli_num_rows($query)` is =5, the form inserts into 5 rows in the database.
2. the remaining outputted forms reloads the page when the submit button is clicked.

This is what I want to achieve:

1. I want each form to be submitted without reloading.
2. I want the form to be inserted in only one row for each.
   Here is my code:

   ```
   <?php

   $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('error');

   mysqli_select_db($con, 'test') or die ('error');

   $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM testing");
   while($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       $id = $sql['id'];
       $post = $sql['post'];

       echo "<p>".$id.". ".$post."<br>";
       $pop_id = $id."pop";    
   ?>
   <style>
   .plop {
       display:none;
       height:200px;
       border-bottom:1px solid #000;
   }
   </style>
       <a href="javascript:;" style="float:right
       ;margin:20px 20px;" onclick="document.getElementById('<?php echo $pop_id; ?>').style.display='block'">comment</a></p><br>
   <div id="<?php echo $pop_id; ?>" class="plop">
   <a href="javascript:;" style="float:right;margin:20px 20px;" onclick="document.getElementById('<?php echo $pop_id; ?>').style.display='none'">close</a>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <form id="my-form">
       <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" />
       <input type="hidden" id="post" name="post" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="post" />
   </form><div id="tutorial"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#my-form').submit(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $.ajax({
                   method: "GET",
                   url: "dote.php",
                   data: $(this).serialize(),
                   beforeSend: function(){
                       $('#tutorial').html("<img src='progress-dots.gif' />");
                   },
                   success: function(status) {
                       $('#post').val('');
                       $('#tutorial').html("");
                   }
               });
           });
       });
   </script>

   </div>

   <?php

   }

   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Change the input type="submit" to type="button" and make ajax on click of button.
For eg.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" />
    <input type="hidden" id="post" name="post" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="post" />
</form><div id="tutorial"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "dote.php",
                data: $("#my-form").serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#tutorial').html("<img src='progress-dots.gif' />");
                },
                success: function(status) {
                    $('#post').val('');
                    $('#tutorial').html("");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Above code will post the data without refreshing the page.

Comment: it only solves my no.2 problem, but the no.1 problem is still occuring

Comment: Is your page still getting refresh?

Comment: Please explain little in detail what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want each comment form to be submitted for its own outputted post and the insertion into the database will be one row for each and not multiple row for each

Comment: You mean multiple forms are getting submit on click of button. Right? If yes, replace "data: $("#my-form").serialize()," with "data: $(this).parent().serialize()," Assuming <form> tag is immediate parent of submit button

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('error');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'test') or die ('error');

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM testing");
while($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id = $sql['id'];
    $post = $sql['post'];

    echo "<p>".$id.". ".$post."<br>";
    $pop_id = $id."pop";    
?>
<style>
.plop {
    display:none;
    height:200px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
</style>
    <a href="javascript:;" style="float:right
    ;margin:20px 20px;" onclick="document.getElementById('<?php echo $pop_id; ?>').style.display='block'">comment</a></p><br>
<div id="<?php echo $pop_id; ?>" class="plop">
<a href="javascript:;" style="float:right;margin:20px 20px;" onclick="document.getElementById('<?php echo $pop_id; ?>').style.display='none'">close</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<form id="my-form-"<?php echo $id; ?>>
    <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" />
    <input type="hidden" id="post" name="post" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="post" />
</form><div id="tutorial"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#my-form-<?php echo $id; ?>').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "dote.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#tutorial').html("<img src='progress-dots.gif' />");
                },
                success: function(status) {
                    $('#post').val('');
                    $('#tutorial').html("");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</div>

<?php

}

?>
```